# Error Bad state: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: flutter

I've been trying to chunk the file and upload it to an AWS presigned URL. For the very first iteration, it works, but after that, I'm getting the error `Error in _getChunkStream: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to` I've tried different approaches, but nothing worked. I've been stuck on this for the past two days. I'm using file_picker to read as a stream. I've tried to create a new stream controller for every iteration and broadcast the stream

```
class UploadRequest {
  String url;
  final String method;
  final String fileKey;
  final Map<String, String>? bodyData;
  final Map<String, String>? headers;
  final PlatformFile file;
  final Function(int)? onUploadProgress;
  late final int _maxChunkSize;
  int fileSize;
  String fileName;
  Map<String, String>? uploadHeader;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? tags;

  UploadRequest({
    required this.url,
    this.method = "POST",
    this.fileKey = "file",
    this.bodyData = const {},
    required this.file,
    this.onUploadProgress,
    required int maxChunkSize,
    required this.fileSize,
    required this.fileName,
    this.headers,
    this.uploadHeader,
    this.tags,
  }) {
    _maxChunkSize = min(fileSize, maxChunkSize);
  }

  Future<void> upload(int partNumber) async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> _tag = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < _chunksCount; i++) {
      print("Calling $i");

      final start = _getChunkStart(i);
      final end = _getChunkEnd(i);
      var chunkStream = _getChunkStream(start, end);

      var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        method,
        Uri.parse(url),
      );

      request.headers.addAll(headers!);

      // Add other fields if needed
      request.fields.addAll(bodyData!);

      request.files.add(http.MultipartFile(
        fileKey,
        chunkStream,
        fileSize,
        filename: fileName,
      ));

      var response = await request.send();

      // Read response
      String result = await response.stream.bytesToString();

      uploadHeader = response.headers;

      _tag.add({"etag": uploadHeader!["etag"], "PartNumber": partNumber});

      tags = _tag;

      // Process the response as needed
      print("Uploaded Req res : $result");

      print(response.headers);

      // Update progress
      _updateProgress(i, end - start, fileSize);
    }
  }

  Stream<List<int>> _getChunkStream(int start, int end) async* {
    print("reading from $start to $end");

    try {
      // Use skip and take directly on the stream without converting to a list
      await for (var chunk in file.readStream!.skip(start).take(end - start)) {
        // Yield the chunk to the stream
        yield chunk;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle any errors during stream processing
      print("Error in _getChunkStream: $e");
    }
  }

  // Updating total upload progress
  _updateProgress(int chunkIndex, int chunkCurrent, int chunkTotal) {
    int totalUploadedSize = (chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize) + chunkCurrent;
    double totalUploadProgress = totalUploadedSize / fileSize;
    onUploadProgress?.call(totalUploadProgress.truncate());
  }

  // Returning start byte offset of the current chunk
  int _getChunkStart(int chunkIndex) => chunkIndex * _maxChunkSize;

  // Returning end byte offset of the current chunk
  int _getChunkEnd(int chunkIndex) =>
      min((chunkIndex + 1) * _maxChunkSize, fileSize);

  // Returning a header map object containing Content-Range
  Map<String, String> _getHeaders(int start, int end) {
    var header = {'Content-Range': 'bytes $start-${end - 1}/$fileSize'};
    if (headers != null) {
      header.addAll(headers!);
    }
    return header;
  }

  // Returning chunks count based on file size and maximum chunk size
  int get _chunksCount {
    var result = (fileSize / _maxChunkSize).ceil();
    return result;
  }

  int _calculateStreamSize(Stream<List<int>> stream) {
    try {
      int size = 0;
      stream.listen(
        (chunk) {
          size += chunk.length;
        },
      );
      return size;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: check [ChunkedStreamReader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html) - the docs say: "Utility class for reading elements from a chunked stream."

Comment: @pskink What is happening is, I'm creating a multipart request for S3. It will give an upload ID, and after that, I'll get presigned URLs. I'll upload the files to those URLs. For example, if my file size is 200MB and the chunk size is 50MB, I'll get 4 presigned URLs, and I'll upload 50MB to each of them. Once that is done, I call a CompleteMultipart API, which will merge all the URLs and make it a final file.

Comment: Here are the relevant AWS documentation links for reference:
- [CreateMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html#API_CreateMultipartUpload_RequestParameters)
- [UploadPart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html#API_UploadPart_RequestSyntax)
- [CompleteMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html#API_CompleteMultipartUpload_RequestBody)

Comment: @pskink I tried this package .But still i'm getting the same bad state 
https://pub.dev/packages/chunked_stream
`Stream<List<int>> _getChunkStream(int start, int end, int chunkSize) async* {
    print("reading from $start to $end");

    try {
      final reader = cc.asChunkedStream(end, file.readStream!);

      yield* reader
          .asyncExpand((chunk) => Stream<List<int>>.fromIterable(chunk));
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error in getchunked stream $e");
    }
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256448/discussion-between-naveen-and-pskink).

Comment: I did not mention any `chunked_strean` package, I mentioned [ChunkedStreamReader](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/async/ChunkedStreamReader-class.html)